# Timezone Updater Tool

Tags: java, timezone

Hola tengo un problema con este código en Java Netbeans 8.2

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
Date fechal=new Date(); 
System.out.println("Fechal: " + fechal); 
SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
System.out.println("Fecha 1 formateada: "+ f1.format (fechal));     
}
```

México ya no usa el horario de verano, entonces cuando invoco la fecha me dice que es por ejemplo 01:20 pm o 13:20 cuando debería ser 12:20 Ya instale el Timezone Updater Tool y ya quedo instalado pero no veo mejora.

Ya instale el Timezone Updater Tool y ya quedo instalado pero no veo mejora.

Comment: ¿Qué valor de regresa `java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getVersions("UTC").lastEntry().getKey()`?

Comment: Versión de las reglas de zona para UTC: 2021a

Comment: Eso confirma que tienes una versión anterior de tzdata, debe ser 2022f o superior. Considera que TZ Updater Tool sólo actualiza una JRE/JDK a la vez, por lo que tendrías que ejecutarlo tantas veces como tantas versiones (instalaciones) de Java tengas, incluyendo la propia de Netbeans. Revisa la ruta del JDK/JRE en: *Tools > Java Platforms > Platform Folder* y aplica ahí TZ Updater Tool; o en su defecto añade otra plataforma más reciente que tenga tzdata actualizada (ej. Java 8u381 o superior) y úsala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo el problema, como te encuentras en Mexico City, te sugiero definas la zona horaria como "GMT-6", de esta forma deberías obtener el valor correcto de la hora.

```
    Date fechal=new Date();
    System.out.println("Fechal: " + fechal);
    SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    f1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-6")); //Time Zone Mexico City

    System.out.println("Fecha 1 formateada: "+ f1.format (fechal));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho, tambien intente con cambiar la zona a Tijuana y tambien resulto